# Reporting Services: Allow charts width to grow

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have a column graph that I would like to automatically grow rather than shrink the size of the bars to fit the defined space.

Is there any way to set the minimum width of a series?
Is there an option to allow the width to grow as necessary?

I know a Tablix and Matrix automatically grow, so I'm hopeful that a chart can be made to do the same.

Comment: I didn't realise that the Tablix can grow automatically - this is something I never figured out; do you have a link to an article that shows how to do this?